# Your startup project '' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2019, onion-architecture

I have an web application that is designed based on **Onion Architecture**. The ORM I used is
`"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.10"` in **Infrastructure.EFCore** layer .My startup project is a **Razor Pages** application. When I use the command `Add-Migration`, this error appears:

```
Your startup project 'MB.Presentation.AspNetCoreRazorPages' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.
```

Is this correct to install this package in **Presentation Layer**?
this is the solution picture:

[image]

Comment: I would asume your startup project is `MB.Application`, just install package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` there, it should be work

Comment: Thank you!  I know that I should install this package on startup project and the application will work. But I'm looking for the right place of EFCore in Onion Architecture.

Comment: Infrastructure layer plz, and the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` serve for difference purpose that's allow EF core CLi to do their jobs, it's not related to data access at all, therefore, both of them on two separate location is fine